# SP Online usage report expose users visiting a site

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph, azure-ad-graph-api

Asking if there is a way to see on who are the specific users who viewed a site? Currently I am only seeing Counts as a report. We are targeting to create a report that can also expose the users who visited a sharepoint site and how many times. this pulled data would be used as a data source for a power BI report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site usage report does not expose individual user data.

I would recommend looking at the audit log in the Security and Compliance Center. You can find more information here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: Thank you for the answer! we ended up using audit logs to pull the required data of what pages our users are visiting at a specified time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, audit log and site usage report will not count this data. You can use power shell to export an excel sheet to view these data.

For example:

```
$UserRecords = $Report | ? {$_.UPN -eq $U.UserPrincipalName} 
    If ($UserRecords) {  
       $UserReports++  
       Write-Host "Writing out data for" $U.DisplayName
       $FileName = "c:\Temp\AuditHistory" + $U.UserPrincipalName + ".csv"
       $UserRecords | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation $FileName }
```

More information:

https://office365itpros.com/2020/05/13/generate-per-user-audit-reports-sharepoint-online-activity/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! we ended up using the audit logs to achieve what we needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional info for the answers related to audit logs. we were also required to pull the audit logs using MS Flow and do an http call. this was achieved by utilizing the API https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/ with a service principal created.

more details on this blog post that I found: https://www.syskit.com/blog/audit-logs-on-office-365/